# How to solve $\int e^{-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}-R}{H}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

How to solve
$$ \int_a^b e^{-\frac{1}{H}(\sqrt{x^2+z^2}-R)}dx$$

z, R, H are constants, a and b are known.

I tried the substitution

$$\displaystyle u=-\frac{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}-R}{H}$$

$$\displaystyle du=-\frac{x}{H\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}dx$$

$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{u'}du=dx$$

and get

$$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{u'}e^{u}du$$

Then how should I proceed ?

Comment: Mathematica could not integrate it either

Comment: With your substitution, I got $$
\left| H \right|e^{R/H} \int {e^{ - u} \frac{u}{{\sqrt {u^2  - (z/H)^2 } }}du} .
$$ It is very unlikely that there is a closed-form expression for this.

Comment: I should have mentionned it : H, R and z are constants.

Comment: Is there a better substitution ?

Comment: Even the *definite* $\int_0^\infty$ would result in [modified Bessels](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32).

Comment: I've defined the bounds of the integral.

Comment: You've "defined" these to be *arbitrary*. This is the same as leaving the integral indefinite.